# Exporting materials

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Im completely new to blender and 3D modeling in general. I have an object that has materials but no texture. I am trying to export the materials as a PNG for a game I'm building. I've been looking around on how to do this and what I have found has said to use UV editing and then export UV layout. When I do this everything comes out fine except that it was the wire frame on it. How do I export the UV's without the wireframe on it?

Comment: Try to find an info how to UV map your models, then you can bake your materials  to texture. But if you are absolute beginner, I strongly recommend to learn the basics first, i.e. by following some beginner tutorials on YouTube (search for Blender Guru channel) or read Blender's manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/

Comment: @JanKadeřábek Okay, thanks!  I find out about baking them to textures and started Doing it but did it wrong as it come out weird.  Ill check the youtube Channel.  Thanks again!